# Is it true that the text-to-speech functionality would make my mac run slower?

Tags: mac, text-to-speech

I have been having some issues with my macbook running very slow.  I read an article which stated that disabling the text-to-speech functionality could make the mac faster. Is that true?

For a year I have been using that functionality to "read" blog posts. Now, on chrome I need to go `edit -> speech -> start speaking` (there is no shortcut). If I re active the text-to-speech would my mac still run slow

Comment: I've never heard that having text-to-speech on could cause your Mac to run slow.  Maybe if your Mac is about 10 years old it's possible but if you have a fairly new Mac I doubt this has anything to do with it.  If you've noticed your Mac running slower recently, see what processes are running and using the most resources.  Chrome is a resource hog, so just using Chrome *could* cause some slowness just on its own.

Comment: You can always check Activity Monitor and see what's hogging resources.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of the "text-to-speech" feature causing a slow down. But other things certainly can. Here is a link to what one Apple user has suggested. There are a number of things to try!

https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-6921